# Set specific headers for static files in SvelteKit

Tags: cors, vite, svelte, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

I need to serve some files from my SvelteKit project with permissive CORS headers.

Some options I've explored:

### Placing the files in `/static`

If I place those files in `/static` I get restrictive CORS headers.

Is there a way to customize headers for static files? I would guess not, based on this conversation: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2060.

### Placing the files in `/lib`

I can place the files elsewhere in the directory structure, then access them using `readFile` from within a `+server.ts` endpoint.

However, if I place the files in `/lib` and build, they do not get copied into the build output at an easily accessible path.

I *can* figure out the correct path manually, but it's brittle and only works when I'm running the pre-built project (i.e. only if I do `npm build; npm preview`, and not if I do `npm dev`).

### Placing the files elsewhere and configuring an alias

Using the same custom endpoint approach as above, in theory I could:

- create a new directory for my files
- add that directory as an alias in `vite.config.ts`:

```json
{
    ...,
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $public: '/public'
        }
    }
}
```

- reference the file using the alias:

```js
readFile(`$public/{params.filename}`)
```

However, when building, Vite does not rewrite `$public` to the correct path in the build output. It would appear that this path rewriting only works in certain situations.

### Bypassing the build process

Again using the custom endpoint approach, I could add a new step to my Docker build to copy the files to a path outside of the SvelteKit build output and then read them from disk at that path.

Unfortunately I then don't get the benefit of any of the packaging that SvelteKit/Vite does when building my assets (e.g. compression).

Comment: Your "quick fix" is great - sure not ideal, but the only thing I found that works.  I did have to modify it slightly (as of SK 2.0.0) -- code:

`const headers = new Headers(response.headers)`
`headers.append('Header-Key', 'header value')`

Comment: @HarlanTWood Yep, I haven't found anything better in the 3 months since I wrote this question. I've promoted the quick fix to a self answer to this question. Hopefully someone will provide a better answer in the future!

Answer (score 1):

For now I have a quick fix in place, which is to:

- place the files in `/static/__public/`, where they will be served by SvelteKit at `/__public/<filename>.js` without the correct CORS headers
- have my `.../public/[filename]/+server.ts` make a fetch to `/__public/<filename>.js`, manipulate the headers in the response and send it on its way, i.e.:

```js
// In /src/routes/public/[filename]/+server.ts

export const GET = (async ({ fetch, url, params }) => {
    const response = await fetch(new URL(`/__public/${params.filename}`, url.origin));
    const mimeType = "replace-me"; // I'm using the mime-types library here, i.e. `mime.lookup(params.filename);`
    const headers = {
        ...response.headers,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `*`,
        'Content-Type': `${mimeType};charset=UTF-8`
    };
    return new Response(response.body, {
        headers
    });
}) satisfies RequestHandler;

export const OPTIONS = (async ({ fetch, url, params }) => {
    const response = await fetch(new URL(`/__public/${params.filename}`, url.origin), {
        method: 'OPTIONS'
    });
    const headers = {
        ...response.headers,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
    };
    return new Response(null, {
        headers
    });
}) satisfies RequestHandler;
```

While it does work, this is suboptimal:

- I have to make an extra request
- The files are being served on two paths: `/__public/<filename>.js` without permissive CORS headers, and `/public/<filename>.js` *with* the correct headers.

Comment: This is the only thing I found that works. I did have to modify it slightly (as of SK 2.0.0) -- code: `const headers = new Headers(response.headers) ; headers.append('Header-Key', 'header value')`